# What happens if a library I use in my project is discontinued, will my app crash?

Tags: java, android

I currently use a number of different gradle libraries in my android project, but what if in the future one of these library is discontinued?

How to plan for these kind of situations?

Answer (score 5):

No.  Your app actually contains every library you use, compiled into the APK.  Gradle downloads them at compile time.  As long as they don't require a server component, an installed version will last forever.  (If it requires a server, and they stop running the server, then of course it won't work).

Now if they were to go and scrub all versions of their artifacts from whatever repository you use, and you didn't have a local copy, then you wouldn't be able to compile a new version.  That would be extremely rare.  You can protect against that by keeping a copy of the libraries checked into source control with your app.